# Synchronize AD Users in SAAS

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, saml-2.0, saas

I need to synchronize users in SAAS, but some clients doesn't want to open the ldap port (389) to access. I already have authenticate the users with SAML, but how would I synchronize the users ?

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] Nor should clients be opening up their LDAP externally to you. Just a bad security practice all around. You'll need to look into providing a REST API (like SFDC or Google or Workday does) for your clients to programmatically manage their own user identities in your system. Much like SAML allows a standards-based authentication method, check out the emerging cloud provisioning standard called SCIM (http://www.simplecloud.info/ if you want to do this in a repeatable manner.

You'll find a lot of big name players involved in SCIM and some 3rd party products already exist (see Ping Identity) that will help you and/or your customers quickly integrate.

HTH.

Comment: I think he is the SaaS provider and wants to sync his user database with the client/customer's ActiveDomain to enable the clients users to login (to give them a SingleSignOn). At least thats what I am guessing from the q :)

Comment: I just re-read that and you're correct. I'll modify my answer. Thx!